# FInd duplicates withtin array based on certain keys using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter, lodash

I have an array like this

```
let data = [{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:1,y:2,z:4},{x:11,y:2,z:3}]
```

Now I want to get only those items whose x,y,z values are the same.so expected output should be

```
{x:1,y:2,z:3}
```

Because `{x:1,y:2,z:3}` has duplicate values but rest of them not so I don't want to get rest of them because they do not have any duplicates. Please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you going to filter and find duplicates with key you know. In above example, `x` will be your unique key that can be passed to find duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

For lodash `4.17.15`,

You can first use `_.uniqWith` and `_.isEqual` to find the unique values.

```
_.uniqWith(data, _.isEqual); // [{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:1,y:2,z:4},{x:11,y:2,z:3}]
```

Then use `_.difference` to remove the unique values from the array, leaving just the duplicates

```
_.difference(data, _.uniqWith(data, _.isEqual)); // [{x:1,y:2,z:3}]
```

Comment: In case of multiple (more than 2) occurrences of similar objects you might have to apply another `_.uniqWith()` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:1,y:2,z:4},{x:11,y:2,z:3},{x:11,y:2,z:3}]

function filterDuplicates(data) {
   let dic = {};
   data.forEach(obj => {
      let strObj = JSON.stringify(obj, Object.keys(obj).sort());
      if(strObj in dic) {
         ++dic[strObj];
         return;
      }
      dic[strObj] = 0;
   })
   return Object.entries(dic).filter(([key, value]) => value > 0).map(([el]) => JSON.parse(el));
   
}

console.log(filterDuplicates(data));
```

Comment: I want to achieve it using lodash

Answer (score 0):

Build an object to track the duplicates and use `Object.values` and `filter`

```js
let data = [
  { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 },
  { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 },
  { x: 1, y: 2, z: 4 },
  { x: 11, y: 2, z: 3 },
];

const all = {};
data.forEach(({ x, y, z }) => {
  const key = `x${x}y${y}z${z}`;
  all[key] = key in all ? { x, y, z } : null;
});

const res = Object.values(all).filter(Boolean);

console.log(res);
```